# Did the code example of geocode() in PostGIS tiger geocoder geocode all records then limit later intentionally?

Tags: postgis, tiger, geocoding

The `geocode` function in PostGIS tiger geocoder extension have [an example of batch geocoding](http://postgis.net/docs/Geocode.html), which seemed to be used by many people. However I'm not sure if the behavior of this example I observed is intentional.

`UPDATE addresses_to_geocode
  SET  (rating, new_address, lon, lat) 
    = ( COALESCE((g.geo).rating,-1), pprint_addy((g.geo).addy),
       ST_X((g.geo).geomout)::numeric(8,5), ST_Y((g.geo).geomout)::numeric(8,5) )
FROM (SELECT addid 
    FROM addresses_to_geocode 
    WHERE rating IS NULL ORDER BY addid LIMIT 3) As a
    LEFT JOIN (SELECT addid, (geocode(address,1)) As geo
    FROM addresses_to_geocode As ag
    WHERE ag.rating IS NULL ORDER BY addid LIMIT 3) As g ON a.addid = g.addid
WHERE a.addid = addresses_to_geocode.addid;`

The example code was supposed to only geocode 3 addresses that not be geocoded then update the table. So you can run this code again and again, each time it will update 3 rows.

With a 10 address table, the example code need 18 seconds to run (I knew the performance in my setup is not good, it used to be much better when I only have 3 states data in SSD. Now I have 100G data in regular hard drive and it is much slower), and 10 seconds in 2nd run.

With a 20 address table, it need 45 s to run, 40 s for 2nd run. With a 500 address table, it keep running before I cancelled it.

This make me believe that the example code actually geocoded all rows in table first, then choose the first 3 results to update the table.

I observed this kind behavior earlier with `limit`:

```
SELECT geocode(address_string,1) FROM address_sample LIMIT 4;
```

will take much longer time if the table is big. While this line always use similar time no matter how big the table is:

```
SELECT geocode(sample.address_string, 1) 
    FROM (SELECT address_string FROM address_sample LIMIT 4) as sample;
```

So I modified the example code into this:

`UPDATE address_table
  SET  (rating, output_address, lon, lat, geomout) 
    = ( COALESCE((a.geo).rating,-1), pprint_addy((a.geo).addy),
       ST_X((a.geo).geomout)::numeric(8,5), ST_Y((a.geo).geomout)::numeric(8,5), 
       (a.geo).geomout)
FROM (SELECT sample.addid, geocode(sample.input_address,1) as geo
        from (select addid, input_address 
                       from address_table 
                       WHERE rating IS NULL ORDER BY addid LIMIT 3) as sample
     ) as a
WHERE a.addid = address_table.addid;`

Now it always run in 5 seconds no matter how big the table is. However there is a new problem: the first row in my table is a bad address. The original code will assign the rating as -1 when it cannot find a match, then later runs will skip this bad address. My modified version didn't update the rating column as -1, so every run will try to geocode it and skip it.

In summary, I have actually two questions:

1. Is the behavior I observed in example code intentional? The document said

   > for large numbers of addresses you don't want to update all at once, 
   >   since the whole geocode must commit at once

I'm not sure what does this means. If you always geocode all table, why limit the output?

2. How to make my modified version set the rating column of bad address as -1?

**EDIT: I solved my 2nd question.**

The `LEFT JOIN` in example code is needed to return a result table that with bad address rating as -1. The new code runs 3~4 seconds for 3 rows every time, no matter what the table size is.

`UPDATE address_table
  SET  (rating, output_address, lon, lat, geomout) 
    = ( COALESCE((g.geo).rating,-1), pprint_addy((g.geo).addy),
       ST_X((g.geo).geomout)::numeric(8,5), ST_Y((g.geo).geomout)::numeric(8,5), 
       (g.geo).geomout)
FROM (select addid 
        from address_table
        WHERE rating IS NULL ORDER BY addid LIMIT 3) as a
    left join (SELECT sample.addid, geocode(sample.input_address,1) as geo
        from (select addid, input_address 
            from address_table WHERE rating IS NULL ORDER BY addid LIMIT 3) as sample
        ) as g on a.addid = g.addid
WHERE a.addid = address_table.addid;`

**EDIT 2**: I run the vacuum commands following suggestion of @LR1234567. It didn't improve the general performance of geocoding, but the example code now have similar performance with my modified version. Maybe the usage in example code depend on the cleaning up of tiger schema?

**EDIT 3**: The example code still have problems.
My data have an invalid address(with incomplete zip code) at first row. The example code will take forever to run if started from first row, and that time is directly related to table size, 271 seconds for 100 row table. Once this invalid row is processed and marked as -1, the example code now can process the normal rows in reasonable time. However my modified code can process the invalid row within 4 seconds.

The only difference between the example code and my version is that I subset the table in from clause instead of where clause.

**EDIT4** Here are the explain analysis results which verified my observation:

1. The example code runs on 100 row table on first time, with first row address invalid:

The first step of scan take 284 s for 99 rows of geocoding

[image: The first step of scan take 284 s for 99 rows of geocoding]

the second step of limit to 3 rows happened after, too late

[image: the second step of limit to 3 rows happened after, too late]

2. My modified code for same table:

The first step of geocoding only processed 3 rows

[image: The first step of geocoding only processed 3 rows]

the second step of limit actually have same starting and end time of first step, so they happened together

[image: the second step of limit actually have same starting and end time of first step, so they happened together]

3. After the first row of invalid address was marked with -1, run the example code again for other rows:

the rows were limited before geocoding

[image: the rows were limited before geocoding]

So this could be something related to how PostgreSQL planning the query if there is an invalid row. Maybe the other people didn't have the invalid row in top then they didn't find this problem. I sorted my input address by zip code so that invalid row appeared at top.

Answer (score 3):

Hopefully this answers your questions

1) You don't want to geocode a whole table at once because of the way Postgres works.  All work in an update gets committed as a single transaction, which means two things

a) If for whatever reason your update crashes in the middle, you lose all work already done in that update.

b) Since postgres commits all as a single transaction, lots of memory and resources are being held up for the period of the update and at a certain point slows things down.

2) Your timings seem pretty bad.  Did you run vacuum analyze across whole hierarchy?

as detailed in - http://postgis.net/docs/postgis_installation.html#install_tiger_geocoder_extension

```
SELECT install_missing_indexes();
vacuum analyze verbose tiger.addr;
vacuum analyze verbose tiger.edges;
vacuum analyze verbose tiger.faces;
vacuum analyze verbose tiger.featnames;
vacuum analyze verbose tiger.place;
vacuum analyze verbose tiger.cousub;
vacuum analyze verbose tiger.county;
vacuum analyze verbose tiger.state;
```

Comment: Thanks, I understand that it's not a good idea to geocode the whole table. That's why I'm confused about the example code. The example code seemed to want to avoid updating whole table, but it actually geocoded whole table before updating 3 rows. My modified version no longer geocoding the whole table now.
I did run the missing_index once I found the performance problem, though I haven't try the vacuum lines. I thought all my downloading happened to tiger_data schema, so I didn't realize I need to update the tiger schema.

Comment: I tried the vacuum lines, no changes were made and no performance difference. That's all right because I'm setting up an AWS box to do the batch job. The pc is only used to test work flow.

Comment: It's really interesting. The vacuum commands didn't change the general geocoding performance, but the example code now runs in similar time with my modified code. It seemed that the example code is good but it need the tiger schema cleaned up, while my modified code don't need that.

Comment: I'm still having problem with the example code for rows with invalid address. My modified version don't have that problem, see EDIT 3 in my question.

Comment: dracodoc,  I'll have to experiment with that.  Nowadays I'd just use LATERAL for that kind of stuff.  I should probably write an example doing that.  The code would be shorter.  Which version of PostgreSQL are you using?  SELECT version();

Comment: 'PostgreSQL 9.4.4, compiled by Visual C++ build 1800, 64-bit'. Besides, please see my EDIT 4 of analysis results. Turned out the example code usually work right except when there is an invalid address in top. If I moved that invalid address to 2nd row, the example code work normally too.

Answer (score 2):

With more experiments and explain analysis, I found that:

1. If there is an invalid address (with incomplete zip code) in first row, the example code will geocode the whole table then limit output later.

The first step of scan take 284 s for 99 rows of geocoding. See more details in EDIT 4 in my question.

[image: The first step of scan take 284 s for 99 rows of geocoding]

2. My modified version don't have this problem.
3. If I move the invalid address to 2nd row, the example code don't have this problem.
4. If the invalid address has been processed and marked with -1, the example code don't have this problem too.

So this unintentional behavior only happened when there is invalid address in first row. I'm not sure if it will happen randomly when the invalid address was in the middle of table, because I'm not sure why the problematic behavior happened in first place. So I'll use my modified version anyway.